# How to instrument gcc?

Tags: gcc, instrumentation

I have to instrument gcc for some purposes. The goal is to be able to track what GCC functions are called during a particularly compile. Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with the architecture of GCC so I need a little help. I tried the following steps:

1) Hacking gcc/Makefile.in and adding "-finstrument-functions" flag to T_CFLAGS. 
2) I have an already implemented and tested version of **start_test** and **end_test** functions. They are called from gcc/main.c, before and after toplev_main() call. The containing file is linked to gcc (the object is added to OBJS-common and the dependency is defined later in gcc/Makefile.in)
3) Downloading prerequisites with contrib/download_prerequisites.
4) Executing the configuration from a clean build directory (on the same level with the source dir): `./../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix="/opt/gcc-4.6.2/" --enable-languages="c,c++"` 
5) Starting the build with "make all"

This way I runned out of memory, although I had 28G.
Next I tried to remove the T_CFLAGS settings from the Makefile and give -finstrument-functions to the make command: `make CFLAGS="-finstrument-functions"`. The build was successful this way but when I tried to compile something it resulted empty output files. (Theoretically **end_test** should have written its result to a given file.)

What do I make wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to track GCC's internal functions as it compiles? Or of what you are compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specifically exclude it from being instrumented, `main` itself is subject to instrumentation, so placing calls to your `start_test` and `end_test` *inside* `main` is not how you want to do it. The 'correct' way to ensure that the file is opened and closed at the right times is to define a 'constructor' and 'destructor', and GCC automatically generates calls to them before and after `main`:

```
void start_test (void)
  __attribute__ ( (no_instrument_function, constructor));

void end_test (void)
  __attribute__ ( (no_instrument_function, destructor));

/* FILE to write profiling information.  */
static FILE *profiler_out;

void start_test (void)
{
  profiler_out = fopen ("profiler.out", "w");
  if (profiler_out == NULL)
    exit (-1);
}

void end_test (void)
{
  fclose (profiler_out);
}
```

Footnotes:

1. Read more about `constructor`, `destructor` and `no_instrument_function` attributes [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). They are function attributes that GCC understands.
2. Read this [excellent guide to instrumentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-graphvis/), on the IBM website.

Comment: Well, let's see whether I understand you correctly:
Your code sketch above goes into a helper file, let's say into Instrumenter.c, what is linked to the project. Furthermore, I have to pass the -finstrument-functions flag to CFLAGS. And that's all? Don't I need to call start_test and end_test functions anywhere?

Comment: @user1437750 - No you don't need to do that. GCC inserts calls the `start_test` ('constructor') and `end_test` ('destructor') before and after `main`, on its own.

Comment: @user1437750 - I added a couple of notes with URLs to the answer itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. According to this page I created my own instrumenter functions what work fine for little examples but in case of gcc I'm still not sure I placed the flags properly.
If I gave the -finstrument-functions in make phase to CFLAGS (`CFLAGS+="-finstrument-functions"`) then nothing happened. On the other hand,if gcc/Makefile.in was modified to<br>
`T_CFLAGS = -finstrument-functions -g`
then the building runned out of memory.
Btw instrumenter.c is also added to gcc/Makefile.in:
OBJS-common = \
...
 instrumenter.o \
...
and
instrumenter.o : instrumenter.c
to the object definitions.

Comment: and yeah, I forgot to add you as a recipient :)

Comment: @mirage - Hmm.. not sure what the problem is. Maybe I'll try it out later this weekend.

Comment: I found the answer in the meantime: `make BOOT_CFLAGS="-g -finstrument-functions" bootsrtap`
One more question I have: how can I get the name of the test passed to gcc to build? I need this information in the main_destructor. Any idea?

Comment: @mirage - *name of the test*? I do not understand exactly what you mean by that. Could you be more clear? Which `gcc` are we talking about here? The one that builds your gcc? Or the instrumented gcc that you're using? And what is 'test' here?

Comment: I mean the final, instrumented gcc. To be specific, I want to dump the result of the instrumented gcc to a file named the same way like the input was. E.g.: `gcc test.c` where gcc is the instrumented one. During the compile I gather some informqtion what i'd like to write out into test.dump file in the main_destructor phase.

Comment: Yes. You can find out the name of the input file. It is available as `const char *main_input_filename` declared in `toplev.c` in the source tree.

Comment: @mirage - It would be nice if you could include your questions in an EDIT to your original question, and then 'answer' them. This will help future visitors. If most of the important stuff remains in comments, its difficult for people to dig out the final solution.

Comment: I guess you'll need to declare an `extern const char *main_input_filename` before your destructor, so that you may access the variable.

Comment: yeah, i've found this one. I'm just not sure whether I can reach its value from the linked instrumenter. (specifically from the main_destructor)

Comment: I tried it out, but this string is not available from the linked instrumenter. However I solved it with an ugly hack: i saved the name of the current test into a file and read when i needed it.
But the good news is that I have further problems, namely after I linked the instrumenter file to the project and added file writing part to the main, then i got errors somewhere deep in the gcc source . It doesn't know size_t for example in filenames.h and a lot of similar error message. I thought that I distract the dependency tree.

Comment: Then I tried to build with --disable-bootstrap but this way the instrumentation didn't run. Any idea?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, I have no idea. I think at this point, you should consider asking on the [GCC-Help mailing list](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/). Here is [the subscription page](http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html#subscribe).